# How can I move .owl-pagination outside the primary owl wrapper? OwlCarousel2

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

It would be great if there was a simple way to move .owl-pagination to another div outside the primary owl wrapper. Wondering if there is a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

It works with standard options: **navContainer** and **dotsContainer**

html

```
<!-- html custom containers -->
<div id="customNav" class="owl-nav"></div>
<div id="customDots" class="owl-dots"></div>
```

javascript

```
$('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    // move navContainer outside the primary owl wrapper
    navContainer: '#customNav',
    // move dotsContainer outside the primary owl wrapper
    dotsContainer: '#customDots',

   // other OwlCarousel2 options
})
```

For OwlCarousel2 issue [663](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/issues/663),

Answer (score 4):

You can move the navigation after init, like in this example:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/navOnTop2.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation:true,
    afterInit : function(elem){
      var that = this
      that.owlControls.prependTo(elem)
    }
  });

});
```