# Owl carousel pagination inside wrapper

Tags: owl-carousel

I want the pagination (dots) to be inside the wrapper, instead of after it. I found this answer: [How can I move .owl-pagination outside the primary owl wrapper? OwlCarousel2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817163/how-can-i-move-owl-pagination-outside-the-primary-owl-wrapper-owlcarousel2)
Which could give me some guidance, but it needs version 2, and that wrecks my page.

Comment: Please before asking a question in stackoverflow, explore information about it and write some code about it, if there is a bug ask it here !

Comment: I've been trying for hours!

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).